# How does the keyboard-event trigger a sibling button's click event? (jsfiddle inside)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

The setup in question can be tested and altered here: http://jsfiddle.net/5hAQ8/9/

I have a small form (basically just an input field with a clear-button). The JavaScript is trivial and just illustrates the problem. Basically it's three listeners on input (keyup), button (click/tap) and form (submit). The HTML is very simple:

```
<form>
    <input>
    <button>X</button>
</form>
```

The X is intended to clear the field, but that's not the point. When someone presses <kbd>enter</kbd>, even while the input is in focus, the button will get triggered. You may test this yourself in the linked jsfiddle above.

Once you press <kbd>enter</kbd> inside the form, you will see three alerts: one for the input, one for the button, one for the form. I can't understand why the button and the form would be involved at all?

My understanding of DOM events would have been a keyboard-event originating from the input, bubbling up to document, but I took every measure to cancel that event. So my question is threefold:

- why does the event get to the `<button>` at all?
- why does the button trigger its listener (which is on click and tap) even though the event is a `keyup`?
- why don't the `preventDefault`s / `stopPropagation`s kick in.

Comment: That's just what browsers do. If a form has just one input in it, you get that behavior for free. It's very useful for things like login forms.

Comment: Enter to submit is not the issue, if you mean that. My issue is with the mixture of events and my inability to cancel those events i do not want to happen.

Comment: Also, when I hit "Enter" in the form, I get the events from the input and the button only; nothing from the form. Just as a suggestion, using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` makes life somewhat more pleasant.

Comment: If you catch "keydown" instead of "keyup", then preventing the default (`event.preventDefaul()`) in that handler is all you have to do.  That will prevent the button "click" event and the form submit.

Comment: Pointy, this is not a beginner's question. The alert is in place to stop the page from reloading. I know about console.log.

Comment: OK sorry :)  Well [here is my fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5cCu/).  I changed the input handler to catch "keydown" and adjusted the logic so that the only thing that's done is to prevent default on key code 13. Since on yours I got the button event first, it would seem that the browsers trigger the "click" *after* "keydown" but *before* "keyup". Why? I don't know; probably a random choice that's become a de facto standard.

Comment: `keyup` is the better option than `keydown`. You want to execute your code _once_ the user has finished typing and _not_ while he's still in the process of typing. This honestly is a weird bug/behaviour, but preventing default behaviour on key code 13 would be a decent enough work around so Pointy is right on that one.

Comment: See [section 4.10.22.2 *Implicit submission*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#implicit-submission) in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: @ninty9notout the problem is that the browsers trigger the "click" on the default submit button *before* "keyup" happens. Thus, your "click" handler on the submit button has no way to know that it's called from a fake click and not a real one. You therefore have to prevent the default in "keydown" if you want to prevent it at all.

Comment: so implicit submission is triggered before keyup. This answers why preventDefault has no chance. The "how does the event get to the button" is because of the default form submit (as defined in html5 spec). Apparently this is triggering click (which i wasn't expecting).

This answers the three-part question pretty well. Thank you everybody who contributed.

I think i'll go with keydown for keyCode==13, and keyup for the rest. Seems the least hackish solution to me.

Comment: i'll post a formatted write-up once i am allowed to by StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer goes back to details in the comments of the question. Thanks to Pointy for many of the details.

**why does the event get to button** and **why click/tap**

The default form submit (as defined in [html5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#implicit-submission) spec). Apparently this is triggering click (which i wasn't expecting).

**why doesn't the preventDefault kicks in**

Implicit submission of the form is triggered before keyup. This answers why preventDefault has no chance. It appears not to be standardized, but every browser i tested did this.

**Possible solutions**

I think i'll go with `keydown` or `keypress` for keyCode==13, and keyup for the rest. Seems the least hackish solution to me. (suggested by ninty9notout, Thanks!)

This answers the three-part question pretty well. Thank you everybody who contributed.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the issue by setting `type="button"` on the button element.
That avoids any default behaviour from the browser.

> Possible values are:
>           submit...,
>           reset..., button: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button